# Storing changes in .properties file that has been read via getClass().getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, properties

I am writing a java web application that reads properties from a .properties file. Since I do not know the absolute path of the .properties file, because it depends on the environment the application will run on in the future, I have to load it with "getClass().getResourceAsStream":

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
message = props.getProperty("testdata");
```

This works as expected. Now I want to change the value for testdata in the file. But I cannot open an Outputstream to write to, because I still don't know the path of the .properties file.

```
props.setProperty("testdata", "foooo");
props.store(new FileOutputStream("?????"), null);
```

Is there a way to get the path of the file or can I use the established Properties-object somehow? Any ideas are welcome that allow me to change the .properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an `URL` by using `getResource()` rather than using `getResourceAsStream()`

You can then use that `URL` to read from and write to your properties file.

```
File myProps = new File(myUrl.toURI());
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myProps);
```

Etc.

Comment: What if the properties file I need to update is in a war or ear file?

Comment: @KevinYang - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application?rq=1

Answer (score -3):

The Properties class includes a store method that can be used to save the properties back to the stream that was read in getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties").

Comment: The store method requires a FileOutputStream, but getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties") only gives me a FileInputStream. If those cannot be converted in a sane way, this approach fails.