# file load in a jar

Tags: java, file-io, properties

I'm loading a prop and saving it

```
File propfile=new File(getClass().getResource("credentials.properties").toURI());
                prop.load(new FileInputStream(propfile));
            prop.setProperty("a", username);
            prop.setProperty("c", password);
            prop.setProperty("b", pbKey);
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream(propfile), null);
```

When i normally run this in netbeans its fine, when its bundled into .jar file it throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)
```

---

now when i use

```
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("credentials.properties");
```

i can read the file , but i can't save the file unless i use the `.toURI()`
as in -> [Storing changes in .properties file that has been read via getClass().getResourceAsStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589012/storing-changes-in-properties-file-that-has-been-read-via-getclass-getresourc)

so when i use toURI() and when i run it (jar file) it would cry out saying the  `URI is not hierarchical`

and when i use `getResourceAsStream` , i couldn't save the file

what should i do?
the properties file is in same package as class is in.

Comment: @ cypronmaya : why does the program need to modify the jar file? I guess you need to revisit the requirement/design.  Consider the case the jar is not writable at all.

Comment: @Jayan i'm trying to build a desktop application where some parameters are set by user like their username/password etc., kinda, to implement that i've wanted to use properties file becoz its easier.

Comment: @ cypronmaya :     You can have some sort of defaults in properties from the jar. Save the modified content some  where else, say in ${user.home}.

Comment: @cypronmaya Jayan is right, have a look at my answer below for a implementation that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to *load* the properties, you shouldn't be using `File` at all - you should use `getResourceAsStream`.

If you need to *save* the properties back again, you can't easily have them in a jar file. You'd need to rebuild the jar file each time you save - ick!

If you *really* need both, you might want to consider having a file which is created the first time you need to save changes: when loading, use the file if it's present, but use the version in the jar file otherwise.

EDIT: If you're building a desktop application and these are basically user preferences, you should look into the [`Preferences` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). Also be *very* careful if you're storing passwords... avoid doing so if you possibly can.

Comment: would you mind if you could elaborate the last part 'If you really need both.......'

Comment: @cypronmaya: Which bit of the suggestion do you not understand? Do you definitely need to save changes? Assuming you *don't* want to start rewriting the jar file, do you have somewhere appropriate you could save the new properties file?

Comment: the part u said 'you might want to consider having a file which is created the first time you need to save changes' to save changes? i couldn't do that in anyway, yes i need to save changes atleast to a temporary file until program closes etc.,

Comment: @cypronmaya: Why can't you do that? And if you only need the changes until the program closes, why can't you just keep them in memory? Why use a file at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
File userFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "myProgram.properties");
if(userFile.exists()) {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(userFile));
} else {
    prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("credentials.properties"));
}

prop.setProperty("a", username);
prop.setProperty("c", password);
prop.setProperty("b", pbKey);
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(userFile), null);
```

(be aware that user.home does not work every time on every machine, but it should work next to every time.)

Comment: *"user.home does not work on all platforms."*  News to me.  In what way does it 'not work'?  On which platforms?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've seen it not working already. Although 'platform' is the wrong word here (I'll edit it) See this question as example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503284/java-system-getpropertyuser-home-returns