# unable to read xsd file from project folder xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to validate the xsd's in my project under xsd folder within WEB-INF.
please find the code which i have developed

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OTAHotelResRQ.class);

JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, reqJAXB);

SchemaFactory sf =SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 

Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("XSD/OTA_HotelResRQ.xsd"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

validator.validate(source);
```

But i am not able to read it from XSD. It is showing following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:///D:/hayyat/softwares/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/XSD/OTA_HotelResRQ.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:322)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
```

So please resolve it my problem.

Regards
Narsi

Answer (score 2):

Put the XSD in classpath (WEB-INF/classes or jar in a lib) and read is from the classpath.

[How to read properties file in web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application)

[Getting the inputstream from a classpath resource (XML file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file)