# Load properties file within a web app

Tags: java, web-applications

Up until now I was able to load the properties files via ClassLoader since it was a standalone app -> jar

```
/**
 * Path and filename for {@code.properties}.
 */
private String propertiesFileName = "./com/config/resources/config.properties";

propertiesFromFile.load(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName));
```

Now I need to use this jar within a web app the problem is that via ClassLoader I get NULL

How can make that inside jar will be able to read is properties file ?

Is there I why via maven ?

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Have you already read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application)?

Comment: Yes I was checking this answer basically I need to remove the dot  
"/com/config/resources/config.properties". this will work when adding the jar to the web app lib but not when running the jar.

Comment: I had some code of my own doing this until I realized it was easier to let spring read my properties files. You can pass in file locations as jvm arguments and override a base set of properties. Best of all the properties are injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced similar issues with different behaviours on different platforms when I use `java.util.Properties`. In the end I settled with using Apache Commons - Java Configuration API:-

```
PropertiesConfiguration properties = new PropertiesConfiguration("my.properties");
String propertyValue = properties.getString("prop.key");
```

The path to my properties files are set in my JVM classpath prefix when I start my container.

Comment: its also an option thanks