# Create Hibernate SqlQuery from .sql file

Tags: sql, hibernate

How can I create a SqlQuery (with method session.createSqlQuery) from a .sql file located in src folder?
My sql file is a simple select.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read query from file

   String queryString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
2. Create sql query

   Query query = session.createSqlQuery(queryString);

Comment: I got this error java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /src/main/resources/QueryDetectionVSFixingGraph.sql

Comment: what kind a project you have?
P.S. try "src/main/resources/QueryDetectionVSFixingGraph.sql"

Comment: It doesn't work. I have a maven project and I also tried with two backslash but nothing.

Comment: i mean architecture of your project. if it's web this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application