# Read file from /src/main/resources/

Tags: java, eclipse, path, relative-path

I am trying to do a web application and have a problem:
I don't know how to open a text file with Java that is saved in the resource folder:

[image: text file saved in the resource folder]

```
 String relativeWebPath ="/src/main/resources/words.txt";  //Import der des Textdoumentes
 String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
 File f = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
```

(The file words.txt)

As you can see on the image I am trying to access words.txt but it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: `/src/main/resources/`, though present in your project directory structure, is probably not a part of the _Web_ path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. /src/main/resources/ is not working. How should I change the directory structure?

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
                         .getResourceAsStream("/words.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Comment: ``Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`` may be a better option, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not work for me. Still can't find the file.

Comment: Remove the "/", just: ``ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("words.txt");``

Answer (score 1):

For best practice, and avoid these problems, put text file (`words.txt`) to WEB_INF folder (this is secure folder for resources). Then:

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
InputStream resourceContent = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/words.txt");
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342095/3728901

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly your answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: @dovy, In this case, you have to maintain two different codes (java standalone, web) just because of the directory issue. I think this is not a good idea.

Comment: what if the file is in the `src/main/resources` folder in a separate .jar? There is no way to move it to the WEB_INF folder of the webapp module...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to find the path to the file you want to open.

```
import java.net.URL;

[...]

URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/words.txt");
String absoluteDiskPath = url.getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access in some other class, like you have a utility package and in that, you have a ReadFileUtil.java class which opens and reads the file, you can do it in the following way:

```
public class ReadFileUtil {

        URL url = ReadFileUtil.class.getResource("/"+yourFileName);
        File file = new File(url.getPath());

    }
```