# Inside a plugin, how to properly get a directory & it's contents from src/main/resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, directory

I am writing a Java Maven plugin in Eclipse, and inside it I want to access some files from `src/main/resources`. Since the number of files and actual filenames should be unknown to the plugin, I plan on storing the files inside some directory that the plugin will know of the name of. So for example, given the file structure:

```
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/dir
src/main/resources/dir/fileA
src/main/resources/dir/fileB
```

The plugin will want to access `fileA` and `fileB`, but won't know their names. The plugin will however know the files it wants to access are in the directory `dir`. **My question is that I want to know how to properly access `dir` from `src/main/resources` in a way where I can easily parse it's contents while the plugin is running.**

I have found many similar questions/tutorials online, but most of them address accessing a *file* that is not a directory (or maybe I just didn't search well enough). For example I found the suggestion to use `classLoader.getResourceStream(resource)` from the question [Read file from /src/main/resources/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703508/read-file-from-src-main-resources) to be useful for file reading. However, when the resource is a directory, reading from the stream returns nothing.

Right now I am doing the following to 1. get the location of the desired directory (basically the JAR) and 2. access the directory's contents, but I want to know if there is a better way since it feels messy:

```
// Get location of desired directory - basically the code's JAR file
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String jarLocation = classLoader.getResource("dir").getFile();
jarLocation = jarLocation.replace("file:","").replace("!/dir","");
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(new File(jarLocation));

// Parse Jar for desired directory content 
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
  if (entry.getName.contains("dir/") && !entry.isDirectory()) {
    // Process entry file in some way
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not a trivial task, but refer to the linked question for solutions.

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for the link, but many of the solutions rely on some form of classLoader.getResourceStream(resource) to read the directory contents which still returns nothing for me. If I do getResourceStream("dir/fileA") everything is file, if I do getResourceStream("dir/") I get nothing. I'm not sure why... if it's due to something super obvious or not but if you have any ideas I'm open to it!

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. But I'd use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource