# Read file from resource folder, InputStream is null

Tags: java, java-11

**Windows 7**, x64, **Java 11**

How to read a file in resources folder in main.

```
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    // Input stream is null.
    InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    return br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I had a similar problem with **test/resources**.

```
private static List<String> readLines(final String filename) {
    try (final InputStreamReader isr = new FileReader(getFileFromResource(filename));
         final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
        return br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to read file: %s", filename), e);
    }
}

private static File getFileFromResource(final String filename) {

    ///////// App.class.getResource is NULL

    final URL url = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
    if (url == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to read resource %s from resources folder.", filename));
    }
    return new File(url.getFile());
}
```

But what worked for **test/resources** does not work for **java/resources**.

What happened in Java-11 or in my code?

---

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15749281/4587961)

```
URL url = ClassLoaderUtil.getResource("test.csv", YourCallingClass.class);
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And this

```
// java.io.InputStream
InputStream inputStream = ClassLoaderUtil.getResourceAsStream("test.csv", YourCallingClass.class);
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    // Process line
}
```

[Other examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703645/4587961) does not help

```
 private List<String> readLines(String filename) {
    // InputStream is null
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    return br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[I solved it!!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409595/4587961)

**maven**

I build my project with maven. After I added a file to resources, it did not go to target directory.

Rebuild the project.

```
mvn clean install
```