# Why I cannot read properties file using getResourceAsStream from WEB-INF/classes in WildFly?

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, wildfly, properties-file

My PC's operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

I created a very simple Dynamic Web Project app in Eclipse:

I have a `app.properties` file in `WEB-INF/classes` directory with these properties:

```
DefaultMaximumBatchSize=1000
DAOFactory=MSSQLSERVER
```

I have a class `AppProperties` which reads the above file into a Properties object at startup using getResourceAsStream:

```
public class AppProperties {
   private static final Properties APP_PROPERTIES;
   static {
      InputStream inputStream = null;

      APP_PROPERTIES = new Properties();

      try {
         inputStream = AppProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties");
         System.out.println("AppProperties: inputStream=" + inputStream);

         if (inputStream != null) {
            APP_PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("AppProperties: Exception occured; e=" + e);
      }
   }

   public static String getValue(String propertyName) {
      if (propertyName == null || propertyName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
         return null;
      else
         return APP_PROPERTIES.getProperty(propertyName);
   }
}
```

I have a listener class `AppContextListener`:

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public AppContextListener() {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        String defaultMaxBatchSize = AppProperties.getValue("DefaultMaximumBatchSize");
        System.out.println("AppContextListener: contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent): defaultMaxBatchSize=" + defaultMaxBatchSize);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }

}
```

I deployed the app to JBoss 4.2.3, run the JBoss 4.2.3 and I get this output in server.log:

> AppProperties: inputStream=java.io.FileInputStream@1adde645 
>   AppContextListener: contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent): defaultMaxBatchSize=1000

Perfect.

I then deployed the same app to WildFly 8.2.1, run the WildFly 8.2.1 and I get this output in server.log:

> AppProperties: inputStream=null 
>   AppContextListener: contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent): defaultMaxBatchSize=null

What happened? What is the correct way to read properties file in WildFly from `WEB-INF/classes` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class.getResourceAsStream()` looks for a resource in all of the directories and jars that constitute the classpath of the application.

So, if you start a java program with

```
java -cp foo;bar.jar com.baz.Main
```

And you use `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/blabla/app.properties")`, The classloader will look for the `app.properties` file under `foo/blabla`, and in the `blabla` directory of `bar.jar`.

Now, in a webapp, what constitutes the classpath of the webapp is

- the directory WEB-INF/classes
- all the jar files under WEB-INF/lib

So, if you call

```
AppProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties")
```

the classloader will look for app.properties in

- `/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes`
- `<all the jar files of WEB-INF/lib>/WEB-INF/classes`

The conclusion is that, to load an `app.properties` file located in `WEB-INF/classes`, what you need is

```
AppProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("app.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer as always. `/app.properties` worked in WildFly 8.2.1 and it also worked in JBoss 4.2.3. Why `/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties` worked in JBoss 4.2.3? Does JBoss 4.2.3 uses different classloader algorithm than WildFly 8.2.1?

Comment: The classpath of a webapp is not a JBoss/Wildfly thing. It's a standard, specified in the Java EE spec. I have no idea why it worked in JBoss.

Comment: I printed out the context ClassLoader `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` and JBoss 4.2.3 gives the output `WebappClassLoader delegate: false repositories: /WEB-INF/classes/ ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@e77d77b` while WildFly 8.2.1 gives the output `ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TestWebReadPropertiesFile.war:main" from Service Module Loader`. TestWebReadPropertiesFile.war is the application deployed. What is that means?

Comment: No idea. I don't know the internals of Wildfly.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I just have to justify to my manager that we need to change the code to upgrade from JBoss 4.2.3. to WildFly 8.2.1 and that's why I was enquiring

Answer (score 3):

JBoss shouldn't have worked.

[Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) retrieves the resource from the *classpath* and the webapp root folder is not in the classpath.

The `WEB-INF/classes` folder is. Use `getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")`, and remember to *close the stream*:

```
 private static final Properties APP_PROPERTIES = new Properties();
 static {
   try (InputStream inputStream = AppProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")) {
      System.out.println("AppProperties: inputStream=" + inputStream);
      if (inputStream != null)
         APP_PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("AppProperties: Exception occured; e=" + e);
   }
}
```

Now, if `app.properties` is always next to `AppProperties.class`, instead of at the root, make the name unqualified (remove the `/`). This will work even when your class is in a package (and it is in a package, right?).

Comment: Thanks. `/app.properties` worked in WildFly 8.2.1 and it also worked in JBoss 4.2.3. Why `/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties` worked in JBoss 4.2.3? Does JBoss 4.2.3 uses different classloader algorithm than WildFly 8.2.1?

Comment: @srh Correct. JBoss uses a different classloader strategy that's not conformant with the Servlet specification. You *can* configure it to be, but the default setup is different. At least it used to be. I think AS7 changed things.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
InputStream inputStream =
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/my.properties");`
```

Comment: why downvote? my answer is correct

Comment: No, it's not. `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` expects a path without a leading slash. It also doesn't explain anything to the OP. And trying to load "my.properties" when the file is named "app.properties" certainly won't help.

Comment: @JB Nizet it doesn expect path without leadin slash check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), also this is just example OP can replace name of file with whatever he needs. and I didn't explain because answer can be easily found on google. If anything you should downvote OP question.

Comment: Almost every question asked here can find its answer on google. That's not a reason to not explain answers. And you pointed me to the javadoc of Class.getResourceAsStream(), which can take a path with a leading slash. Not the same as ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream().