# How to access src/main/resources from a generated exe

Tags: java, maven, installation, exe, launch4j

I am using maven and I am creating an application that needs to get files from `src/main/resources` upon running an `exe`.

I used this to generate an exe upon build > http://www.hascode.com/2012/08/creating-a-windows-executable-from-a-jar-using-maven/

I am getting an error that it cannot access the files inside `src/main/resources` when running the `exe` file.

I use this to get the files from src/main/resources

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
File[] files = new File(classLoader.getResource("files").getFile()).listFiles();
```

When I run it in eclipse, it runs but when I run it using exe,

using eclipse: 
No error

```
DEBUG file:/C:/Development/Java/eclipse/workspace/app_sample/target/classes/files
DEBUG /C:/Development/Java/eclipse/workspace/app_sample/target/classes/files
```

using exe:

```
DEBUG file:/C:/Users/User.Name/Desktop/just%20some%20directory/App.exe!/files
ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Guessing: The compiled program is looking for `src/main/resources/` in the working directory, i.e. where it is being executed. Please post your code where you are trying to access this directory.

Comment: can you post how do you get files from src/main/resources ?

Comment: ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application