# Docker image build with maven doesn't see static files

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab-ci

I have a simple Java backend build with Maven. When I create .jar file with `mvn clean install`, I can run it and everything works fine.

However, when I deploy it to Docker, the server runs, but when I make a GET call, the backend doesn't see static .png file located in `src/main/resousces/`.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/main/resources/logo.png (No such file or directory)
```

The image is uploaded to docker with this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

maven-build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - maven3-jdk11
  except:
    - tags
  script:
    - mvn deploy -B -U

maven-release:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - maven3-jdk11
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - mvn deploy -B -Prelease-profile -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnError=false
```

(This is my first time working with Maven and Docker, so if the information I provided is not sufficient, please leave a comment.)

Comment: How are you referencing the file in your code?

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack your jar file and check if .png file in it. If not, you need to package a jar with the resources folder. If yes, so you need to specify the path to file using classpath.

Comment: It's there in `BOOT-INF/classes` folder. Could you specify what you mean by using classpath?

Comment: You can see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I managed to solve it using java [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Originally, I loaded the .png file like this:

```
Image logo = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create("src/main/resources/logo.png"));
```

I changed that to following and now it works like charm:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
Image logo = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(classLoader.getResource("logo.png")));
```

I accepted Eugene's answer to boost his reputation, he moved me in the right direction.